# Data persistence after call to webservice iOS

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, persistence, nsuserdefaults

Sorry for my English.
I have many problems in achieving data persistence after call the webservice .
Everything works correctly but I need to use that data in other methods .
As seen in the image once charge data on the screen then I want to give the user the option to use them well or load new data . But not as saving the data recovery webservice .
I was trying to use `NSUserDefault` but neither work .
From already thank you very much , any response is helpful .
Regards!

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel2: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let newVC : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    let telefono = myLabel2.text!
    newVC.recibirString = telefono
}
@IBAction func mostrarAlgo(sender:AnyObject) {

 //something

}


}
```

SecondViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var tel: String = ""
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel5: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel6: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel7: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel8: UITextField!
var recibirString = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myLabel1.text = recibirString

    performRequestAndUpdateUI2(myLabel1.text!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func performRequestAndUpdateUI2(tel:String) {
    WebService.llamarWebService (tel,completionHandler: { datos in
        guard datos.count == 5 else {

            self.myLabel8.text = ("El número ingresado no está registrado.")
            return
        }

        guard datos[0] as! String == "OK" else {
            print("not everything was OK")
            return
        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.myLabel3.text = datos[0] as? String
            self.myLabel4.text = datos[1] as? String
            self.myLabel5.text = datos[2] as? String
            self.myLabel6.text = datos[3] as? String
            self.myLabel7.text = datos[4] as? String
            self.myLabel8.text = ("Usted está registrado.")

           //need save this data
        }

    })
}


@IBAction func guardarDatos(sender: AnyObject) {

// do something
}
}
```

WebService:

```
class WebService{

var telefono = ""


class func llamarWebService(telefono:String, completionHandler: (datos:NSArray)->()){

    let urlPath = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com.ar/xxxxxxxxxx/forwarder_number?phone=\(telefono)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var arreglo:NSArray!
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!,completionHandler: {data,response,error -> Void in

        if (error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        let nsdata: NSData = NSData(data: data!)

        arreglo = self.retornarDatos(nsdata)
        completionHandler(datos: arreglo)
    })

    task.resume()
}


class func retornarDatos(nsdata: NSData)-> Array<String>{

    let datos = NSString(data:nsdata,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let partes = datos?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    var arreglo : [String] = []

    for i in partes!{
        arreglo.append(i)
    }

    return arreglo
}

}
```

[image: First View]

[image: Second View]

Comment: Show the code you tried for saving to user defaults, and reading the details back. Explain what didn't work.

Comment: I was trying something like that but not to call it from the first view or truly is saved.

Where it says "need save this data"

defaults.setObject(self.myLabel7.text, "label7")